# How cocoapods works with xcode 6 on OSX 10.9.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

please help me on this. I've updated my xcode to xcode6 and now I'm not able to  run my application on it due to cocoapods errors. I searched around the web also follow the below steps :

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences (Menú Xcode-Preferences)
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
5. Uninstall from a terminal window cocoapods (all installed versions prompted)
   $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
6. Uninstall xcodeproj (all installed versions prompted)
   $ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj
7. Install xcodeproj
   $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
8. Install cocoapods (retry a second time if fails with a error)
   $ sudo gem install cocoapods
9. Run pod –version to verify that it worked

But Still I'm getting error on pods. My application is running well in **xcode 5.1.1** but not in **xcode 6**. I'm getting error on "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m" file and the error is semantic issue.

One more thing when I'm doing **pod update** in my project folder where the podfile installed, **Removing SSToolkit** shown and SSToolkit folder removed from project folder. But in xcode 5.1.1 **SSToolkit** is there.
please someone help me to rid of this issue....
thanx

Comment: I doubt cocoapods supports Xcode 6 yet; why would it?

Comment: But some places people suggested that it support please follow the link http://iosnow.net/?p=36

Comment: That says "Yosemite", which is not 10.9.3.

Comment: yes,and people also saying xcode 6 is working in 10.9.3 , I also tested test app on xcode 6. But my app having cocoapods not working only, others are working fine...

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the error messages you would get some help.  Also tag your questions correctly.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I'm getting error on "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m" file and the error is semantic issue (use of undeclare identifier) and if I remove this error then some other error comes and the .m file is in pods, but if I run the app on xcode 5.1.1 then there is no error

Comment: it is just another reason why cocoapod should not be used. shame.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `SDWebImage`, not with cocoapods. because of the presence of the `getter` attribute on the `executing` and `finished` properties, the newer version of XCode is not auto-synthesizing the variables.

There should be [a compatible version RSN](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/748), but to work around it for the time being, you should change your podfile for the package to add the version:

```
pod 'SDWebImage', :head
```

Once it gets released you can remove the reference to `:head`

**Note** this is a real 'short time window' question - This package will probably start working again in a few days without intervention from anyone barring a `pod update`.

Comment: thanx Petesh, should i do this from terminal ?

Comment: one more thing that if I solved this issue (like currently it is **_executing** , if I replace it with **executing** then error gone) then new issue come which is also belongs to pods target..   Should I wait for few days and not to change any thing in codes, please suggest me.

Comment: you edit the `podfile`, adding the reference to `:head` in file and do a `pod update` to get the refreshed source for the package - so a terminal is the simplest place to do that from. Changing `_executing` to `executing` won't fix the problem.

Comment: Thanx @Petesh will check and let you know once back from meeting, thanx for your support.

Comment: Hi @Petesh I did the **pod 'SDWebImage', :head** and try to update the pod but getting error **Ignoring xcodeproj-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine xcodeproj-0.17.0**. please let me know what I should do..

Comment: It sounds like xcodeproj didn't install correctly. You should reinstall it, and make sure it installs correctly, by following the recommendation and doing `sudo gem pristine xcodeproj` and a `sudo gem pristine cocoapods`, as the error it generated is probably related to the broken `xcodeproj` package. Additionally, you should have documented **all** the errors you saw as you were installing the gems. This helps for diagnosis of issues as well as keeping records. The vanishing `SSToolkit` may be related to the specification in your podfile.

Comment: yes Petesh, as you suggested for SDWebImage it looks solved, but vanishing **SSToolkit** creating error now, please help me on this, how can I keep **SSToolkit** in my pods

Comment: You need to show your podfile. When I have `pod 'SSToolkit'` explicitly in a podfile it remains whether I'm using XCode 5 or XCode 6, so you have something else affecting it's presence.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the SDWebImage.

```
Just replace _executing with self.executing.
```

And clean your code and build it again.

Thanks
Sarabjit Singh